# Access Control issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Ok this is stumping me mainly because of the lack of experience I have with access control. I have two folders I need to keep away from users. Payroll and Banking.

I went into security and took away all the users. I made a new group called access granted and added it to both folders. I then gave full control to the group. I then added a few days to this group.

I tested with partial success. I can only get into some folders and subfolders/files. I made sure I clicked on the option for all subfolders.

This is my layout

C:(folder) --> permissions granted to admin,access (full control)

when I look at the problem files/folders no one has any permissions I don't even see the group or admin.

what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What are the permissions on one of the sub folders you can't get into?  It sounds like the permissions didn't replicate fully, or that you have a deny rule at a lower level.

Comment: there is no deny rule. For an example lets say I have C:\folder\2012\... files in here. The folder will have right permissions but 2012 will only have admin and not the group I added on folders.. The files will be the same.. Or.. I wont have any names listed under group/names

Comment: I think I might be on to something. Under C: I have the followings groups/usernames admin,creater,everyone,access,system,users. To get rid of the users for C:\payroll and c:\banking I had to uncheck allow inheritable permissions. Could this be my problem? because if I click it again it adds users back to the names and groups and I dodnt want all users to have access. Should I get rid of users right off the C: and just create separate groups. Example would be Employees and another supervisors. Gives employees access to everything but those two folders. And then gives supervisors access to all

Comment: Are you using the Advanced security settings?  (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726071.aspx)

Comment: is there a easy way to do this all in AD?

Comment: yes I`m using it.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this in AD, I have done something sort of similar using scripting in power shell though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using Advanced Security settings I'd start at your top level folder you want set permissions on, apply the correct groups / users etc. and make sure you check;

```
Replace all existing inheritable permissions on all descendants with inheritable permissions from this object
```

This may take some time depending on the depth of the folder structure and the number of files.

(more detail here -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730772.aspx)

Comment: Great stuff, glad it worked.